# Disable keyboard on start up

Tags: 14.04, boot, scripts, keyboard

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.
I have a script placed on `/etc/init.d` to disable it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get the device id of the Synaptics TouchPad
id=$(xinput list --id-only 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard')

xinput float $id
```

It works fine, but I need it to run before the login screen appears, so I've made:

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/disableKeyboard.sh /etc/rc3.d/S99disableKeyboard.sh
```

But it doesn't work, does someone know why it's not running during boot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a script at startup, before login, you would edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your commands.

Just add this line:

```
/etc/init.d/disableKeyboard.sh
```

One line above the line:

```
exit 0
```

---

```
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.

# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution bits.
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a script/command before the login screen, you would have to edit

```
/etc/rc.local
```

and add your commands to the end of it. Make sure to end the script with `exit 0`

So, in your case

```
/etc/init.d/disableKeyboard.sh
```

would be added to `/etc/rc.local` and

```
exit 0
```

would be added to `/etc/init.d/disableKeyboard.sh`